# Trying to get responsive window and shapes using p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making my way through JavaScript tutorials (using p5.js) and was interested in coding a responsive screen with four shapes that scale down and stick next to each other while doing so.

Is defining a separate variable for y enough, or would it be better to redefine all the shapes by a new set of x and y variables? Window height/width *seems* like it should be the correct code to use.

My code:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  noStroke();

  var labelw = window.innerWidth/8;
  var labelh = labelw/4;
  var sectionw = window.innerWidth;
  var sectionh = window.innerHeight;

  // Red
  if(window.innerWidth/2 < window.innerHeight){
    fill(200, 50, 50);
    rect(0, 0, sectionw/2, sectionw/4)
  }

  // Blue
  if(window.innerWidth/2 < window.innerHeight){
    fill(50, 50, 200);
    rect(sectionw/2, 0, sectionw/2, sectionw/4)
  }

  // Green
  if(window.innerWidth/2 < window.innerHeight){
    fill(130, 230, 130);
    rect(0, sectionh/2, sectionw/2, sectionw/4)
  }

  // Purple
  if(window.innerWidth/2 < window.innerHeight){
    fill(190, 100, 230);
    rect(sectionw/2, sectionh/2, sectionw/2, sectionw/4)
  }

  // label1
  fill(50)
  rect(0, 0, labelw, labelh)
  fill(255);
  textSize(labelw/10);
  text("Test Label\nTestIdeo, 19xx-20xx",0, 0, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do two things:

First, you need to detect when the screen is resized, and resize the canvas when that happens. The `windowResized()` and `resizeCanvas()` functions come in handy for that. See [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowResized) for more info.

Second, you just need to use the `width` and `height` variables to draw your shapes. The `width` and `height` variables are automatically updated when you resize the canvas.

Putting it all together, it would look like this:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
} 

function draw() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(0, 0, width/2, height/2);

    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(width/2, 0, width/2, height/2);

    fill(0, 0, 255);
    rect(0, height/2, width/2, height/2);

    fill(255, 255, 0);
    rect(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2);
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Comment: Where does the `width` and `height` variables came from?

Comment: @Rich They come from p5.js.